# SQL Server upgrade re-initializes subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, replication, upgrade

I recently, in a test environment, upgraded my SQL Server Distributor from 2012 to 2017. The upgrade went off without a hitch but I noticed that after the upgrade was completed all of my subscriptions from the publisher using that distributor were re-initialized.

- Is this expected behavior?
- Is there anyway to prevent this from happening if this is the expected behavior?

Comment: I have not tried an inplace upgrade when replication is involved, but an [inplace upgrade will require reinitializaiton](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/upgrading-a-replication-topology-to-sql-server-2016/).